# Event handler logic in winforms for having one checkedbox selected at a time

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

```
    namespace explorer
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\test");
                FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos();
                checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
            }

            private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
            {
                for (int ix = 0; ix < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; ++ix)
                if (ix != e.Index) checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(ix, false); 
            }
            //removed irrelevant parts of the code
        }
    }
```

I forgot how to build an event handler for the checkedlistbox. 
I need one selected. I have multiple files but I need just one selected by a check box.

Comment: can you please refactor your question ..this makes zero sense

Comment: If you need only one item selected at any time, why not use radio buttons instead of a checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn off the event handler or use a variable as a flag to avoid a stack overflow since you are unchecking items in an ItemCheck event:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
  checkedListBox1.ItemCheck -= checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
  for (int ix = 0; ix < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; ++ix) {
    if (ix != e.Index) {
      checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(ix, false);
    }
  }
  checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
}
```

An example using a variable:

```
bool checkFlag = false;

private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
  if (!checkFlag) {
    checkFlag = true;
    for (int ix = 0; ix < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; ++ix) {
      if (ix != e.Index) {
        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(ix, false);
      }
    }
    checkFlag = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops, missed this! :) Still flag variable is sure better solution for him. Turning event handlers on/off is really not good practice or he must do that in single thread or lock and in try/finally block.

Comment: @0x49D1 I've included both examples for the OP.

Comment: yes , worked with the flags and checkedlistbox properties ItecmCheck:checkedListBox1_ItemCheck.

Comment: Another example of a bad question rescued by a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `List<FileSystemInfo>` collection and add every checked file to it on check and remove on uncheck. The handler itself is already created as i see(`checkedListBox1_ItemCheck`). May be you should consider to write the question more clearly, because may be i understood you not exactly right?